# Is the Nikon 24-120mm f/4 G ED VR AF-S NIKKOR Lens compatible with the Nikon D5500?

Tags: nikon-d5500

I'm new to photography, I got an offer of 24-120mm & d5500 in cheap price, I would like to know is lens 24-120mm and d5500 are compatible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/496/what-do-all-those-cryptic-number-and-letter-codes-in-a-lens-name-mean)

Comment: @Hueco, I'm sorry, I was mistaken. I missed the detail regarding AF-S at the proposed dupe: _(compatible with bodies without focus motor)_. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the lens-camera combination you've specified should work. You can use the following resources to check other combinations:

- Nikon USA:

  - [Which NIKKOR Lens Type is Right for Your DSLR?](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/learn-and-explore/a/tips-and-techniques/which-nikkor-lens-type-is-right-for-your-dslr.html)
  - [Lens Compatibility Chart](https://www.nikonusa.com/Images/Learn-Explore/Photography-Techniques/2011/Which-Nikkor-is-Right-for-You/Media/NIKKOR-lens-compatibility-chart.pdf) (pdf)
- Nikonians: [Nikon Camera and Lens Compatibility Chart](https://www.nikonians.org/reviews/nikon-slr-camera-and-lens-compatibility)
- Lenshero: [Nikon camera lens compatibility](http://lenshero.com/nikon-lens-compatibility)
- Ken Rockwell: [Nikon Lens Compatibility](https://kenrockwell.com/nikon/compatibility-lens.htm)

Comment: @scottbb Thanks for finding the Nikon chart.  I couldn't find it earlier.