# Does Nikon D3300 and Nikon AF-P DX NIKKOR 70-300mm f/4.5-6.3G ED VR Lens work together?

Tags: nikon-d3300, af-p

I have a Nikon ***D3300*** camera body and now i am planning to buy a zoom lens. And i have shortlisted this ***Nikon AF-P DX NIKKOR 70-300mm f/4.5-6.3G ED VR*** lens to purchase. But i am very confused that is all features of this lens is compatible with D3300 camera body ?

Comment: See https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/102054/57929

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/92678/15871) to [What are the differences between these two Nikkor 70-300 lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/92666/15871) for a fuller look at the compatibility of AF-P lenses with various models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This lens is compatible with D3000 series cameras from the D3300 onwards, D5000 series cameras from the D5200 onwards, and D7000 series cameras from the D7100 onwards. The D500 is also compatible. Please note that compatible cameras may require a firmware update.

[Source](https://www.nikon.co.uk/en_GB/product/nikkor-lenses/auto-focus-lenses/dx/zoom/af-p-dx-nikkor-70-300mm-f-4-5-6-3g-ed-vr)

I believe the firmware update would be necessary if the D3300 is using version 1 of the firmware, because that didn't support AF-P.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your detailed answer. One question: what minimum firmware version is required in camera for this lens ?

Comment: As far as I know, there are only two versions, and it needs the more recent one. In theory it's easy to upgrade: you don't need anything beyond the camera and the ability to copy a file onto the SD card (and if you don't have that, you'll have troubling getting the photos off it). I've never done it myself, so I can't tell you how similar theory is to practice.